# bulk insert using EntityFramework-Plus

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-plus, entity-framework-extensions

I was planning to use [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki) for bulk operations however i am not sure if it supports bulk insert.

So for example, i have `Paren`t entities and i want to insert `Child` entities in bulk how do i dot that using EF Plus

In code below number of parents could be between 1000-2000 range and number of children are 10-20. I want to add same children for each parent, if condition satisfies

```
public async Task AddChildern(IEnumerable<Child> children)
{
    var ids =  GetIDs();
    var result = _dbContext.Parent.Where(x=> ids.contains(x.ID)).ToListAsync();
   foreach(var p in result)
   {
         foreach(var child in children)
         {
               var flag = CanAddChild(child);
               if(flag)
               {
                    p.Children.Add(child);
               }
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: @johnatan Magnan why haven't you added batch insert to EFPlus though??? it doesn't make any sense (since I don't tend to install EF Extensions)

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

This library doesn't support `BulkInsert`.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library supports BulkInsert but it's not free.

*(EF Plus is powered by this library)*

In your scenario, since it looks child entity doesn't have a direct relation to the parent (No navigation property or parent ID), you should use the `BulkSaveChanges` method.

```
public async Task AddChildern(IEnumerable<Child> children)
{
    var ids =  GetIDs();
    var result = _dbContext.Parent.Where(x=> ids.contains(x.ID)).ToListAsync();
    foreach(var p in result)
    {
         foreach(var child in children)
         {
               var flag = CanAddChild(child);
               if(flag)
               {
                    p.Children.Add(child);
               }
         }
    }
}

// ...code... 

_dbContext.BulkSaveChanges();
```

**EDIT:** Answer Comment

> Child does have ParentID

Depending on how the relation is set, you could also do a direct BulkInsert.

```
_dbContext.BulkInsert(result.SelectMany(x => x.Children));
```

Comment: Child does have ParentID